# System.QueryException: List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject3

Tags: apex, failing-tests, twilio

In the test class I am getting the error as above one?

`Class.TW_RestAPI.getTwiML:  Class.TW_RestAPITest.testPostRestService`

```
@istest
public class TW_RestAPITest {

    static testMethod void  testPostRestService() {

        Account acc=new Account();
        acc.name='Test';
        acc.AccountNumber='';
        acc.Site='';
        acc.Owner_Phone_Number__c='';
        Insert acc;

        Profile p = [select id from profile where name='System Administrator'];
        User u = new User(alias = 'utest', email='unit.test@unit.test.com',
            emailencodingkey='UTF-8', lastname='Unit Test', 
            languagelocalekey='en_US',
            localesidkey='en_GB', profileid = p.Id,
            timezonesidkey='Pacific/central time', 
            username='unit.test@cap.com');

        System.runAs(u) {
            Group g=new Group();
            g.type='Queue';
            g.name='Twilio Requests';
            insert g;
            QueuesObject q1 = new QueueSObject(QueueID = g.id, SobjectType = 'Case');
            insert q1;
        }

        String JsonMsg;

        Test.startTest();

        //As Per Best Practice it is important to instantiate the Rest Context 

        RestRequest req = new RestRequest(); 
        RestResponse res = new RestResponse();

        req.requestURI = '/services/apexrest/TW_RestAPI';  //Request URL
        req.addParameter('To', '+31234567890');
        req.addParameter('From', '1390296387');
        req.addParameter('Body', 'Hello');

        req.httpMethod = 'POST';//HTTP Request Type

        RestContext.request = req;
        RestContext.response= res;

        TW_RestAPI.getTwiML(); //Call the Method of the Class with Proper       Constructor 

        Test.stopTest();

    }
}
```

my twilio rest class

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/inboundmsg/*')
global without sharing class TW_RestAPI {

    public TW_RestAPI() {

    }

    @HttpPost
    global static void getTwiML() {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse resp = RestContext.response;
        resp.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
        system.debug(req.headers);

        String respon;
        String toPN =  req.params.get('To');
        String fromPN = req.params.get('From');
        String msgBody = req.params.get('Body');
        String areaCode = fromPN.substring(2,5);
        String prefix = fromPN.substring(5,8);
        String last4 = fromPN.substring(8);
        String formattedPhone = '(' + areaCode +')' + ' ' + prefix + '-' + last4;
        System.debug('FORMATTED PHONE IS: ' + formattedPhone);               

        List<Account> lAcc=[Select id,Owner_Phone_Number__c,Business_Phone_Number__c from account where Owner_Phone_Number__c=:formattedPhone or Business_Phone_Number__c=:formattedPhone];

        Id twilioGroupId=[select id from group where name='Twilio Requests' and type='queue' ].id;
        datetime dt = System.now()-1;
        List<Case> lCase=[Select id from case where accountid=:lAcc[0].id and createdDate > :dt];
        Case c=new Case();
        if ( lCase.size() == 0 ) {
            if ( lAcc.size() > 0 ) {
                c.AccountId=lAcc[0].id;
            }
            c.Issue_Detail__c=msgBody;
            c.Origin='Text';
            c.phone__c=formattedPhone;
            c.ownerid=twilioGroupId;
            Database.DMLOptions options = new Database.DMLOptions();
            options.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule = false;
            c.setOptions(options);

            insert c;
            respon='Thanks for creating the case. Your case number is'+c.casenumber;
            resp.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(respon);
        }

        SMS__c s=new SMS__c();
        if ( lCase.size() == 0 ) {
            s.Case__c=c.id;
        } else {
            s.Case__c=lCase[0].id;
        }
        s.subject__c=msgBody;
        s.message_date__c=system.now();
        s.Type__c='Inbound';
        if ( c.Phone__c != null ) {
            s.phone_number__c=c.Phone__c;
        } else {
            s.phone_number__c=formattedPhone;
        }
        insert s;
        // Build your TWiML here.
    }
}
```

Comment: We don't have any way of knowing what lines numbers are. You need to mark that in your code.

Comment: I am guessing your error is in the `TW_RestAPI` class, if adjusting the profile query didn't help. Can you share the code here?

Comment: ashock, when you post code, after pasting it into your post, please select it and click on the `{}` pre-formatted text icon so that it's legible to anyone who reads it. It's always a good practice to look at the preview pane of your post to fix any problems before posting it. There was a great deal of your post that wasn't visible. that's why you have 4 people have voted so far to close it. I took the time to look before voting.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what line it's on, I can only guess but my assumption is that it's on your Profile query. If you are going to assign it to an SObject instance, you need to make sure you limit your query. This is because even with your `name='System Administrator'` filter, you may get multiple results because `name` is not unique and you could have duplicates.

So just do this..

```
Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='System Administrator' LIMIT 1];
```

Or, alternatively you can query to a list and assign it.

```
Profile p;

List<Profile> profiles = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='System Administrator'];

if(!profiles.isEmpty()) {
  p = profiles.get(0);
}
```

Edit: Now that we see more of your code, it can be any one of the queries that tries to assign to an SObject. Another example of this is the query to get the **twilioGroupId**. Try implementing either the `LIMIT` or querying out a list as implemented above.

Answer (score 0):

You have a custom profile you've created also called system administrator. I'd recommend changing your query as follows:

```
Profile p = [select Id from profile where name = 'system administrator' order by createddate asc limit 1];
```

This will always return the default system administrator profile.

Comment: Thanks. After doing still I am getting the same error.This is my error in the developer console.